# How can I duplicate a RailsEventStore event while maintaining meta-data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-event-store

The scenario is that I have two ActiveModels: `Invitation` and `Guest`.
I've published a bunch of events to the event stream of an invitation and at some point that invitation is accepted and subsequently a guest is created. I would like to copy the events on the event stream of the invitation across to the event stream of the guest.

I've thought of duplicating using `dup` the original events, updating the stream field to be the guest's event stream but this will violate the unique constraint of the event_id field. So I would like the EventStore's `publish` mechanism to handle the persistence of the event.

I've thought of copying the `data` attribute of the original events across to new instances of the events and using `publish` but then I would get metadata (`request_id`, `remote_ip`, `timestamp`) on the event that does not reflect that of the original events which is important to keep for audibility.

Is there some technique to perform this kind of transfer / duplication of RailsEventStore events?

Comment: I guess I can actually publish a new instance of the event and the call `event.update(metadata: old_event.metadata)`

Answer (score 1):

There is a technique — linking. In recent Rails Event Store releases (since v0.22.0) you're able to link an existing event to other streams: https://railseventstore.org/docs/link/. It retains the data and metadata.